# How to get Servlet response in a Javascript page

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

i have a servlet where i have a list of attributes that is populating from database.Now i have to catch the list of a js page and process those data.I am able to call the Servlet from the js page and also created the list in the Servlet but now i want to get the response back to the js page ,this is so far i have done..

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>            
        function doajax(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "AccountDetails",
                type: "post",
               // dataType: "json",
                data: { "mobileNo":"01234567890", "fullName":"Jeet Chattertjee" },
                error:function(){
                    //alert("error occured!!!");
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data.fullName + "\n" + data.mobileNo);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

data: { "mobileNo":"01234567890", "fullName":"Jeet Chattertjee" }, this portion is only for testing that the servlet is called or not.

Comment: in `url: "AccountDetails",` set proper URL for your servlet

Comment: AccountDetails is working properly sir.servlet calling is  running fine.i just want the response back to my js page.

Comment: ok, then change `alert(data.fullName + "\n" + data.mobileNo);` to `alert(data);`

Comment: no sir its not working. :-(

Comment: what is the url of page which performs ajax call and what url you're using to test that AccountDetails is working?

Comment: the code that i wrote as question is responsible for the calling the accountDetails servlet & in the servlet i have done String a=request.getparameter("mobileNo");a=request.getparameter("fullName"); to check the servlet is working

Comment: I cannot help until you start answering my questions, what are the URLs?

Comment: sorry sir but i did not get  by what u mean by URLs i am running it in a localhost so how can i give you the URLs  http://localhost:8084/D3Application/ajaxresponse.jsp

Comment: yes, it is URL, but I need to see both URLs

Comment: only one URL is generating i am unable to take the response back to the servlet so the other URL is not generating

Comment: so, you do not have URL for AccountDetails servlet which you can call from browser? because exactly this one should go in url argument of ajax call

Comment: so what should i do to get a response back

Comment: you need to create JSP which can be called from browser, and call AccountDetails in it

Comment: i am doing that sir  its a jsp page that i wrote in the post  i just copied the script portion

Comment: you can do this in the same page, but than you need proper input handling, create separate - for understanding it will be better right now

Comment: what do you mean by separate?? here jsp page is separate and aslo servlet is separate .i am not doing all things together ??? will you come online sir??i will explain better you in chat plz plz.

Comment: can you give me your mail is sir ??